# For loop error (JAVA)

Tags: java, for-loop

I have been trying to get this for loop to execute but i get an error saying that it is not a statement.

Code:

```
for(num1; num2==0; num2--){
        test1 = num1*num2; 
        test = String.valueOf(test1);
}
```

The variables are declared earlier as int.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: `nul1` isn't initialised. You need to have `num1=0` or something. If you haven't declared it before, use `int num1=0`.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is `num1 is not a statement.` this is because... `num1` is NOT a statement. The first part of a for-loop expects an initialization. You must have an assignment in this part. Change your loop to something like:

```
for (num1=10; num2==0; num2--)
```

Just replace 10 with the initial value you actually want for num1. If you wish to bypass initialization, it is perfectly legal to do

```
for ( ; num2==0; num2--)
```

Comment: This solution accomplished what I was looking for. thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can change it to this (depending on what the logic of your program is) :

```
for(num1 = x; num2==0; num2--){//x is some meaningful value
        test1 = num1*num2; 
        test = String.valueOf(test1);
}
```

Please not toe the for Statement in [java doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to initialize something, just leave it blank.

```
for(; num2==0; num2--){
        test1 = num1*num2; 
        test = String.valueOf(test1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

or if you wanna keep the value of num1 just get rid of the `num1` in `for`. like this:

```
for(;num2==0;num2--)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems with this code. First off what are you even trying to do? You should initialize num1, and you should change the condition. Right now you are saying that you only want this to execute when num2 is equal to 0. Why would you use a for loop for that? Did you mean greater than or equal to 0? That would make a lot more sense. In general the structure is this

```
 for(int num1 = 0; *INSERT SOME CONDITION, INCREMENT OR DECREMENT HERE){
         //SOME STATEMENT(S) HERE
 }
```